# How to get into the OnCreateView function in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I try to call a Fragment from an Activity.
But the OnCreateView function from the fragment doesn't work, it doesn't fire.

Here's my bit of code:

Activity:

```
private RadiusFragment rf;

onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

   rf = new RadiusFragment();
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class RadiusFragment extends Fragment {

private LinearLayout rootLayout;


public RadiusFragment() {

}
public RadiusFragment newInstance() {
    return new RadiusFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    System.err.println("asdfsdf"); //I never see this line
    this.rootLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.pref_map_radius, container, false);

    return rootLayout;
}
}
```

Comment: none of the answers helped you?

Answer (score 0):

you are just instantiating an Object of your `Fragment` , you have to Add your Fragment to your Activity by **FragmentManager** to Create a `Fragment` Properly.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
YourFragment frag = new YourFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.placeholder,frag, "frag");

fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: @hassler23 : what have you done? it's the way it should be, maybe there is something else wrong.

Comment: @hassler23 : and try edited answer , i forgot a line to initialize FragmentManager!

Answer (score 0):

Only Using this line

```
 rf = new RadiusFragment();
```

you can't call your Fragment. You need to add it to FragmentManager. Here you are just instantiating an Object of your Fragment

```
 FragmentManager FMmanager = getFragmentManager();
 Fragment detail = new RadiusFragment();
 FragmentTransaction ft = FMmanager.beginTransaction();
 ft.add(R.id.myFragment, detail);
 ft.commit()
```

Comment: I have no id for my Fragment, or I just can't find it.

Comment: In your xml file just add one FrameLayout with the id of myFragment

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the framework that this fragment belongs to this activity and whatever will be the content displayed by the Fragment that should be part of a container of activity. So when you are making this this transaction, then you need to commit it(as a confirmation, i guess).

Pulled directly from Android developer [site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit()
```

**updated**

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, rf).commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just `instantiation` of a `Fragment` pretty much like instantiating any other Object.
i.e

```
String a=new String();
```

`onAttach(),oncreate(),onCreateView()` etc.. are a part of Fragments [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) events.

To actually have these lifecycle methods()  of a `Fragment` execute, you need to attach it to the activity via FragmentTransaction.[See](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/12/programmatically-add-fragment.html)